# What the code does and what input it should receive

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, intel

This is question from an assembly exam.
The question:
What should be the input for the below code ? 
What the below code does ?

[image]

I tried to do it with pen and paper in order to trace it but I couldn't figure out what it does and what argument it should receive.

any idea ?

Comment: It depends on the ABI, e.g. WIN32 and Linux x86 have different calling conventions.

Comment: OK - I've fixed your tags for you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function implements N-way switch, `call P` instruction immediately followed by array of functions.

```
...
; Here: EAX = index of function (0..N-1)
call P
dd N ; number of functions in the array
dd Func0_Addr, Func1_Addr, ..., Func(N-1)_Addr  ;  array
; Return address after function terminated
...
```